# Multivariable residual analysis and goodness of fit

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, residuals, goodness-of-fit

I am reading the paper [Statistical Modeling: The Two Cultures (2001)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1009213726) by Leo Breiman.

In section 5.2 he claims:

> Residual analysis is similarly unreliable. In a discussion after a presentation of residual analysis in a seminar at Berkeley in 1993, William Cleveland, one of the fathers of residual analysis, admitted that it could not uncover lack of fit in more than four to five dimensions.

As an explanation for why this is true he states:

> With higher dimensions, the interactions between the variables can produce
> passable residual plots for a variety of models. A residual plot is a
> goodness-of-fit test, and lacks power in more than a few dimensions.

I struggle to see why this is true. In particular, why does the number of dimensions matter?